# Managed .NET application starter

Tags: c++, .net

I want to write an application which starts a .NET application depending on the computer supported .NET version. I think, I need to check the already installed .NET version and start the matching application.

Example:

I start a native C++ application which starts the correct VB.NET application for the currently supported .NET version.

My target: Get latest supported .NET version.

Comment: @MartinMeeser no it still don't answer my question. it points how to get executable .net version, I want system supported .net version

Comment: @MartinMeeser you have it the wrong way round...

Comment: @slugster thanks, its **really** duplicate. (I really don't know how to search...)